# Spring Data ElasticSearch JSON date format cause NullpointException

Tags: json, elasticsearch, serialization, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Data ElasticSearch **v4.2.x**, my data was returned in JSON String.

Here is the problem,I tried to parse JSON string to Object,then I got "java.lang.NullPointerException".I have a Date field with these annotations,I'm sure this field is causing this problem:

```
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, name = "created_at", format = DateFormat.basic_date_time, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT+8")
    private Date createdAt;
```

Comment: It won't have any problem with Spring Data ElasticSearch v4.0.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the type as `FieldType.Keyword`, you would need `FieldType.Date`.

The `@JsonFormat` annotation is ignore by Spring Data Elasticsearch.

And please, stop using the old `java.util.Date` class and use the classes from `java.time` instead, they are now available since Java 8.

Comment: I found that it was my serialization configuration problem, but your suggestions still help me a lot!